# How Can I replace my second and third index of array with last index of array _c# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Actually I have a list like

```
oldList= ['First','Second','Third',.....'Seventh'];
```

newArray should be like that

```
newArray=['First',.........'Seventh','Second','Third']
```

so How can I provide ordering like that with linq c#?

I mean my first element should be kept at old place. but I have to skip second and third elements to end of the list

Comment: Do you have fixed length of the array?

Comment: while its possible to do, Linq isn't really made for index based manipulations.

Comment: @Wug How do you know that he wants to order numbers and not their textual representation ?

Comment: Is it *necessary* to use LINQ for this?  Just curious why LINQ is your requirement.  Reminds me of the STL rotate() fxn in C++.

Comment: I mean my first element should be kept at old place. but I have to skip second and third elements to end of the list

Comment: I know but my boss is wanted me to do like that so I have to find out how can I code with linq

Comment: @Nacereddine: He wants to order things of some sort, the values are irrelevant and were provided to better illustrate the movement.

Comment: It really depends if you need performance or simplicity imo. The simplest would be to add the array to a List and then use simple add/remove syntax.

Comment: sounds like a step in a shuffle algorithm

Comment: Is your real code using strings as in your example here or are they objects with more properties that can be used to sort on?

Answer (score 1):

Weird requirement, but you can use `OrderBy` even in this case:

```
var newArray = oldList.Select((t, index) => new { t, index })
                      .OrderBy(x => x.index == 1 || x.index == 2)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.index)
                      .Select(x => x.t)
                      .ToArray();
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/qJOlv

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* do this in LINQ, though it might not be the most efficient:

```
var newArray = oldList.Take(1)
    .Concat(oldList.Skip(3).Take(4))
    .Concat(oldList.Skip(1).Take(2))
    .ToArray();
```

However, if your original container is a `List<T>` you can do things a little more efficiently:

```
var newList = oldList.GetRange(0, 1)
    .Concat(oldList.GetRange(3, 4))
    .Concat(oldList.GetRange(1, 2))
    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**:

For kicks and grins I went ahead and timed several of the proposed methods, and it looks like @L.B's `Get/Add/RemoveRange()` comes on top:

Over 100,000 iterations:

- Skip() / Take() took 82 ms (0.00082 ms / call)
- GetRange() / Concat() took 69 ms (0.00069 ms / call)
- OrderBy() / ThenBy() took 145 ms (0.00145 ms / call)
- Add/Get/RemoveRange() took 21 ms (0.00021 ms / call)

Of course, we're getting into microoptimization here, so I'd say go with the one that makes the most sense to you and is the most maintainable.  But it looks like L.B's solution is the most performant (and is easy to read as well).

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is already a list, you can skip the first line

```
List<string> oldList2 = new List<string>(oldList);
var tmp = oldList2.GetRange(1, 2);
oldList2.RemoveRange(1, 2);
oldList2.AddRange(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is designed for querying data sources to produce new results, not mutating existing data.

The general approach I would use to solve this problem:

```
var second = array[1];
var third = array[2];

for(int i = 3; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i-2] = array[i];
}

array[array.Length-2] = second;
array[array.Length-1] = third;
```

If you really, really need to use LINQ, I'd do something like this:

```
var newArray = array.Take(1)
          .Concat(array.Skip(3))
          .Concat(array.Skip(1).Take(2))
          .ToArray();
```

Note that this approach iterates the data source 3 times; that's just fine if it's actually an array or list, but if, in reality, it's just an `IEnumerable<T>` thats the result of some query or complex operation that would be bad.